# Parse does not register device for push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

There is a strange behavior in Parse's Push Notification. You can download a blank project and here and do some experiments https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-starter-project/latest

To register Push Notification, we need this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Then, in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, we include:

```
[PFPush storeDeviceToken:newDeviceToken];
```

Here are the cases:

Case 1. If your phone don't have a version of the app, and you run the code, it will register the device for Push Notification - Everything works well.

Case 2. If you don't use the code initially by removing it from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Of course, the app will not register the device for Push Notification. Then, you insert code. With the old app still in your phone, running it won't register the device; but if you uninstall your old version of the app, and install the new app with the inserted code, the app will register the device.

Right now, our app is in case 2 situation. When users update the app from the Store, the app won't register their devices for Push Notification unless they remove the old version first. This is not an ideal way to update the app with Push Notification feature.
Do you have any way to update the app and register for Push Notification without deleting the old version first?

Answer (score 1):

Using `NSUserDefaults`, you can set a flag that marks whether or not the device is registered for notifications.  After you register them for notifications, set the flag to yes:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Registered"];
```

In app did finish launching with options, check this and only register them if this is `NO`.

Now then, for people who already have the app installed, they won't necessarily restart their app, and so they won't necessarily go through `appDidFinishLaunching...`

But you can try to register them at other points in the app.  Do you have a mainmenu or some common place that virtually every user is guaranteed to go through at some point?  If so, insert some code like this:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Registered"]) {
     // run the code to register and then set the flag to YES
}
```

Comment: I do have a common place where all users will go through.